# What is the time complexity of my Newton Method and Bisection algorithm?

Tags: python, algorithm, big-o, bisection

I'm very new to Big O, and I've been struggling to assess the time complexity of my two algorithms, which I'm supposed to compare for a school project.

**Bisection:**

```
import time


tid_0 = time.perf_counter_ns()

x_0 = -20000                       #Interval
x_1 = 20000

fortsæt = True
while fortsæt:
    f_x0 = x_0**3+2*x_0+4        #f = x**3+2x
    f_x1 = x_1**3+2*x_1+4         #Finder y værdier

    x_m = (x_0+x_1)/2           #Midtpunkt
    f_xm = x_m**3+2*x_m+4        #Midtpunkt y-værdi

    if f_x0 * f_x1 > 0:
        print("ERROR: Interval ugyldigt")
        exit()

    print(x_0, x_m, x_1)

    if f_x1 * f_xm < 0:         #Hvis = negativ tal
        x_0 = x_m
    elif f_x0 * f_xm < 0:
        x_1 = x_m

    if x_1-x_0 < 0.0009:        #Stopper While-loopet
        fortsæt = False


total = time.perf_counter_ns() - tid_0


print("total tid: " + str(total) + "ns")
```

**Newton Method:**

```
import time

tid_0 = time.perf_counter_ns() #Påbegynder tidtagning af programmet

x_0 = 20000  #Definere et startværdi x_0

fortsæt = True

while fortsæt:
    f = x_0 ** 3 + 2 * x_0 + 4  #Funktion f(x)
    f_d = 3 * x_0 ** 2 + 2    #Differentieret funktion f'(x)
    x_n = x_0-f/f_d         #Find x_0 - f(x_0) / (f'(x_0 )) = x_1
    print(x_n)

    if x_0 - x_n  < 0.0009:  #Stopper While-loopet, hvis forskellen mellem de to nulpunkter er 0,009
        fortsæt = False

    x_0 = x_n


total = time.perf_counter_ns() - tid_0

print("total tid: " + str(total) + "ns") #Printer den endelige køretid
```

Speaking from my best understanding, I suppose my Newton Method algorithm is O(n) in worst case scenario and O(1) in best care. However, I'm not too sure.

Also, the important variable here is *x_0.*

Could someone please clarify and tell me if I'm right or wrong? Thanks in advance!

Comment: what do you consider `n`?

Comment: @Marat Sorry, I consider n as x_0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TLDR:** it depends on the function, so, perhaps, the question is not applicable.

**Explanation and assumptions:** both of these algorithms are looking for a function zero. I assume you define n as `1/e`, where `e` is the desired precision.

The first algorithm, bisection, is O(log mn), where m is the width of initial interval. Proof: we're doing binary search through mn subintervals.

Complexity of the second one, however, is dependent on the function. For a linear function, it will be `O(1)`. For some functions, it will take forever to converge (eg: `y = sin(x) + 2 - x / 1000000`). So, the answer depends on the function, and not only class of the function (linear, quadratic etc.) but, in some cases, also specific coefficients AND the choice of `x_0`.

The exact convergence properties are defined by higher order derivatives.
In this particular case, the first order derivative is always negative so it will converge; however, without `2x` term it will have a point of inflection which will throw `x_n` into infinity.

Protip: it is more readable to

```
while True:
    ...
    if condition:
        break
```

**UPD:** assuming `n` is the distance of `x_0` from function zero, in this particular case:

In the update step, the delta (`f/f_d`) is proportional to x. We're looking for a number of deltas that will sum up to n. Sum of arithmetic progression (n) is O(N^2), where N is the number of steps. So number of steps is O(sqrt(n)).

**Important note:** as stated above, this is not complexity of Newton Method in general. This applies only to this particular function and will not generalize even to other functions of the same class. The question itself doesn't have much of a practical sense (e.g. we can find zero in a closed form) and it is not a particularly impressive analysis. Please, use with care.

Comment: Both of the algorithms are only intended to be used with the specific function shown (x^3 + 2x + 4)

Comment: Alright! Thanks for the help. I'm not too experienced Big O, so I apologize if it's gibberish.